# Get highest custom field value from last x months

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

in Wordpress, I've got a category called "Reviews" where I assign a vote (in a custom field called 'rate') to every single post I create in this category.

Now I'm trying to get the review with the highest rate in the last X months.

The rate ranges from 0 to 10, with one decimal number (ex. 5.3, 7.4, 9.1).

How can I do this? Use WP_Query or direct DB query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get the highest rating:

```
SELECT max(cast(meta_value as unsigned)) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='your_meta_name'
```

But post meta data does not hold the date/time value for you. You need to think a way to insert date value as well.